# Unterminated 's' command with 's/([\^][^])//g'

Tags: linux, bash, sed, rhel

I am trying to find any caret (^) characters in my file, and delete them and the subsequent character whenever they exist. I am running this in bash.

Any time I try and run the sed to do so:

```
sed -i 's/([\^][^])//g' myfile.txt
```

I get the below error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated `s' command
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do if the `^` is at the end of a line? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Same behaviour - I didn't even consider that you guys would worry about this edge case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `[^]` is unfinished because sed is using the `]` following the carat `^` as a negative list of characters, there is a missing `]` (`[^]]`) needed. But that will match a closing `]`, nothing you want (I believe).

What I believe you intend is to match a carat: `\^`. But what you wrote (`[\^]`) will not match a carat either. That will match either a backslash `\` or a carat `^`:

```
$  echo 'abc\def^ghij'
abc\def^ghij

$ echo 'abc\def^ghij' | sed 's/[\^]//g'
abcdefghij
```

But even that is not what you have written:

> find any carat (^) ... and delete them and the subsequent character whenever they exist

If the intended subsequent character is any character, use: `\^.`
If the subsequent character is any character that is not a carat, use: `\^[^\^]`
Or simply: `\^[^^]`

```
$ echo 'ab\cd^^ef^gh' | sed 's/\^[^^]//g'
ab\cd^fh
```

That is:

```
sed -i 's/\^[^^]//g' infile
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

The section `[^]` is not a character class; the `]` bracket is the first character of the negated character class and the code is looking for the next `]` (treating all of `)//g` as part of the character class) and not finding then end marker, leading to the error.

In the positive case, you can use `[][]` to look for a close square bracket or an open square bracket in a character class.  The negative version would be `[^][]`.

Using `[^]]` would stop the error message — you then just need to fix the regex to do what you intend.

Note that by default, the parentheses are interpreted as parentheses, not as grouping metacharacters (you'd need `\(…\)` for that).  In fact, there's no need for the grouping, so the parentheses are dropped from the discussion below.

The fix to your regex moderately clear when I re-read the question.  You're seeking to delete the caret and the next character after it.  That is a little ambiguous; if the caret is at the end of the line (so the next character is a newline), should the newline be deleted as well?  I'm going to assume not.  I also assume that `^^` should be deleted; the question says 'any caret (^) characters in my file, and delete them and the subsequent character' without saying 'unless the next character is a caret too'.  Clearly, the regexes can be tweaked if either assumption is wrong (though the newline assumption is harder to deal with, but quite a margin).

```
sed 's/\^.\{0,1\}//g'
```

This looks for a caret (avoiding character classes) and the next character, if there is one, on the same line — the `\{0,1\}` notation means 0 or 1 repeats of the previous expression.

If your variant of `sed` supports extended regular expressions, you'd be able to use `sed -E 's/\^.?//g'` (Mac OS X and BSD) or `sed -r 's/\^.?//g'` (GNU).

Character classes consisting of just a caret are not really supported by POSIX.  The `[\^]` notation is a character class consisting of a backslash and a caret ('or a caret'?):

```
$ echo 'abc\de^Afg' | sed 's/[\^].\{0,1\}//g'
abcefg
$ echo 'abc\de^Afg' | sed 's/\^.\{0,1\}//g'
abc\defg
$ echo 'abc\de^Afg' | sed -E 's/\^.?//g'
abc\defg
$ echo 'abc\de^Afg' | /opt/gnu/bin/sed 's/[\^].\{0,1\}//g'
abcefg
$ echo 'abc\de^Afg' | /opt/gnu/bin/sed 's/\^.\{0,1\}//g'
abc\defg
$ echo 'abc\de^Afg' | /opt/gnu/bin/sed -r 's/\^.?//g'
abc\defg
$
```

(Plain `sed` is Mac OS X `sed`; `/opt/gnu/bin/sed` is GNU `sed`.)

Answer (score 2):

> *find any carat (^) characters in my file, and delete them and the subsequent character*

Let's take this test file:

```
$ cat myfile.txt 
a^2 b^2 c
```

I believe that this does what you want:

```
$ sed  's/\^.\?//g' myfile.txt
a b c
```

As you know, `^` is normally regex-active character.  We need to escape it so that we can match literal `^`.  In regular expressions, `.` matches any character.  Thus, `\^.` matches a caret followed by any character.  The regex `\^.\?` matches a caret and the following character if there is a following character.

Comment: That won't delete a caret at the end of a line, but it is not hard to fix that — and `\^.` only matches a caret followed by any character other than a newline.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It seems reasonable to interpret the OP's statement that way.  Answer updated.